# How can I make robolectric call `onCreate(bundle)` and not `onCreate()`

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-dialogfragment, robolectric, dialogfragment

I want to test MyDialogFragment class.

Its `setArguments(..)` is called and then it should be read on `onCreate(bundle)`

How can I make robolectric call `onCreate(bundle)` and not `onCreate()`